# the neighboorhood of a node of an abelian form(Plumbing a cylinder )

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am reading this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611409.pdf

On page 41 in the section Plumbing a cylinder it is writen:

> by (4.1), a simple pole of an Abelian differential has a neighborhood which is isometric to a half infinite cylinder.

I do not understand that part. The following is the preceding part where is shown equation (4.1)

> Translation surfaces. Let $X$ be a Riemann surface with a nonzero Abelian differential ω, and let Z(ω) be the discrete set of zeros of ω. Every point of X which is not a zero of ω has a neighborhood U and a conformal map $φ: U → \mathbb{C}$ such that $ω|_U = φ^∗(dz)$. The conformal map φ can be defined explicitly by $φ(z) = \int_{z_0}^z ω$ for a choice of base point $z_0$. These coordinates φ are unique up to translation by a constant. We can also put ω in a standard form in the neighborhood of a zero or a pole at $z_0$.There is a neighborhood U of $z_0$ and conformal map $φ_0 :(U,z_0) \to(\mathbb{C},0)$ such that

> $ω|_U =φ^∗_0(z^ndz)$, if $z_0$ is not a simple pole; or  $φ^∗_0(a dz/z)$, if $z_0$ is a simple pole with nonzero residue $a$.
> This is  equation (4.1).

I will appreciate any suggestion on this. Thank you.

Comment: For starters, the author says that an abelian differential is a holomorphic $1$-form on $X$, and then starts referring to the order of a pole at $z_0$. He certainly does not explain where the half-cylinders come from. Perhaps it helps to think about $z=re^{i\theta}$ in $\Bbb C$; then $\omega = a\frac{dz}z = ai\,d\theta$, and the half-cylinder comes from $\Bbb R_+\times S^1$.

Comment: It gave me an idea. Thank you very much for your help!